# SOLIDITY: Proper syntax for bytes32[] array when testing a function on Etherscan's "write contract" page?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, etherscan

What is proper syntax to enter a bytes32[] array when testing a function on etherscan?

I'm trying to use etherscan to test one of the functions of my contract (for a merkel proof), and I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Every time I enter it I either get this error:
[bytes32 array error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eWuC.png)

or I get this error:

```
invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="\"0x68aa8fd7a2aa7169bfd0dc0914a90c36297f074572463edfd39ec755d066c46e\"", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)
```

this is the bytes32[] array data I'm trying to pass:

```
[
'0x68aa8fd7a2aa7169bfd0dc0914a90c36297f074572463edfd39ec755d066c46e',
'0xa61882556ead5de1c795d9da903ce06f699cbc9608efedbc50a67376cd86a947',
'0x6590db9e2f69783f6465b2a60565b43a3b3376cbd4b37585df77f48b76f977c5'
]
```

And here's how I'm declaring the variable in the function:

```
        bytes32[] calldata proof
```

I've used this function before in other contracts, and I have entered these through etherscan before, I just can't seem to get it right this time.

Can anyone help me with the right syntax to enter this 3 value bytes32[] array into etherscan?